# SQL Server CASE when nvarchar(50) doesn't end in number letter letter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I have a table with > 3million rows but some of the data in one of the columns is wrong - I want to make it NULL when it's wrong.

I want to create a CASE WHEN 'wrong' THEN = 'NULL'. The column data type is nvarchar(50) and each series should end in a number, letter and letter i.e. 1AA, 1AB or 2DA etc etc. Everything that doesn't match the final permutation of number, letter, letter combination I want to convert into NULL.

```
UPDATE T1
  SET T1.ABC = CASE
     WHEN RIGHT(ABC <> number, letter, letter)
     THEN ABC = 'NULL'
     end
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `CASE WHEN YourColumn LIKE '[0-9][A-Z][A-Z]' THEN YourColumn END`? You aren't very clear here.

Comment: `CASE` is an **expression** (like `a+b`) which **returns** a single, atomic value - you cannot use it as a flow control statement to optionally execute one set of code vs. another.

Comment: `UPDATE T1 SET ABC = NULL WHERE ABC NOT LIKE '%[0-9][A-Z][A-Z]'`

Comment: Changing the query over and over doesn't help. The current expression `N RIGHT(ABC <> number, letter, letter)` is simply invalid. `RIGHT` only accepts a string and a length

Comment: And using the string `'NULL'` is simply evil. Either make the field nullable or store an empty string. Finally, `CASE` is an expression and *must* return a value in all cases. You're looking for a much simpler `WHERE` that only matches the "wrong" fields

Comment: Thank you - the WHERE clause has done the job.

Comment: Do you mean _number_, e.g. `'65536'` and `'2.71828'`, or _digit_, e.g. `'2'`? Must the letters be uppercase?

Answer (score 3):

To set invalid columns to NULL, you can use an UPDATE statement with a WHERE clause

```sql
UPDATE T1
SET ABC = NULL
WHERE ABC NOT LIKE '%[0-9][A-Z][A-Z]'
```

The wildcard `%` represents zero or more characters. Therefore, this LIKE pattern ignores the beginning of the text and tests the 3 last characters of it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Combination of answers has helped me.

```
  UPDATE T1
  SET T1.ABC = REPLACE(RIGHT(RTRIM(ABC ), LEN(RTRIM(ABC ))-3), ' ','')
  WHERE ABC LIKE '%[0-9][A-Z][A-Z]'
```

And the rest have been left as NULLs

Answer (score 0):

adding another possible method without using regex

```
UPDATE T1
  SET T1.ABC = CASE
                   WHEN try_cast(left(col1,1) as int)<> null and try_cast(left(right(col1,2),1) as int) = null and try_cast(right(col1,1) as int) = null 
     THEN T1.ABC = T1.ABC
                else ABC = NULL
     end
```

The above method will update all the records which is time-consuming and a heavy load on the server. Rather we can filter the records and then update them.

```
UPDATE T1 SET T1.ABC = NULL where
CASE WHEN try_cast(left(col1,1) as int)<> null and try_cast(left(right(col1,2),1) as int) = null and try_cast(right(col1,1) as int) = null THEN 1 else 0 end = 1
```